# DrRacket keyboard shortcut for α-rename

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, racket, rename

How can I bind a keyboard shortcut (e.g. F2) to [α-rename](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/buttons.html?q=rename#%28idx._%28gentag._12._%28lib._scribblings%2Fdrracket%2Fdrracket..scrbl%29%29%29) in DrRacket, available as `rename foobar` in the context menu brought up by right-clicking on a variable name?

The [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html?q=keyboard#%28part._defining-shortcuts%29) boils down to "call a magic function name from the [API](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/implementing-tools.html)", but I'm having a hard time finding that operation in said API.

Comment: Found the answer in the history file, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the History file for DrRacket version 6.0

```
Added keybindings for the items in the Check Syntax popup menu,
notably c:x;m to rename a variable, c:x;d to just to the
definition of an imported variable, c:x;n to go to the next
occurence of a variable, and c:x;b to go to the binding occurrence
of a variable.
```

So ctrl-x, m  ought to do the trick.

Comment: One has to uncheck "Keyboard shortcuts in menus" for this to work. The checkbox can be found in `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Editing tab` → `General sub-tab` → `Keyboard shortcuts in menus`.